# How to use min.js in vite2?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vite

such as vue.min.js
I try to external the vue in build.rollupOptions,and import

//vite.config.js

```
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue', 'vuetify']
   }
```

// index.html

```
 <script src="/lib/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/lib/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

and download the vue.min.js and vuetify.min.js ,but it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

the legacy vue.min.js is a umd file but vite need esm version.
so just download the `vue.esm.browser.min.js` to replace vue.min.js is Ok.

just add external like this:

```
    rollupOptions: {
      // 外部化vue 和 vuetify
      external: ['vue']
    }
```

and import vue in index.html like this:

```
...
<head>
...
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <!-- script -->
  <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "/lib/vue.esm.browser.min.js" //(where the file is)
        }
      }
  </script>
...
</head>
```

Now you can run vite build in your project, and it works.

## But I didnt find esm version of vuetify2.

The net give us some plugins to import external umd which should be pre-handled:

- [vite-plugin-external](https://www.npmjs.com/package/)
- [vite-plugin-cdn-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-cdn-import)

But i still not make them work,if you have an example successfully,pleace udpate a answer!!!